# ssh to another host, run an script involving the other script, how to only kill the other script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

suppose I am in 192.168.0.100, and in ~/, there are two bash scripts:

loop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    loop=1
done
```

and, parent.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    ./loop.sh
    sleep 1
done
```

now, i switch to machine 192.168.0.101, and i want to ssh to 192.168.0.100 to run parent.sh. I use command

```
ssh myname@192.168.0.100 "cd ~/; ./parent.sh"
```

then, i switch back to machine 192.168.0.100, I run the command

```
killall loop.sh
```

what i want is to kill loop.sh and wait for 1 sec then parent.sh will restart loop.sh,

but what i really get is that parent.sh is killed together with loop.sh.

So i am confused, why this would happen, and how to really achieve what i want?

Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry to say that I tried your setup and it worked as you intended: loop.sh restarts one second after killing it.

Comment: I run that in my environment but it works as expected too

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still not works as i intended, i don't know if restart machine could fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Before kill the loop.sh process

   F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD

   0 S 1047      9984  9983  0  80   0 -  1291 wait   14:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash - ./parent.sh
   1 S root      9996     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 14:46 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:2]    
   0 R 1047     10001  9984 99  80   0 -  1290 -      14:46 ?        00:00:02 /bin/bash - ./loop.sh

If you kill the loop.sh process that process is execute again and again due to parent.sh process execute the loop.sh process every 1 seconds. 

After loop.sh process is killed

   F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD

   0 S 1047      9984  9983  0  80   0 -  1291 wait   14:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash - ./parent.sh
   1 S root     10005     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 14:46 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:2]    
   0 R 1047     10036  9984 99  80   0 -  1290 -      14:46 ?        00:00:02 /bin/bash - ./loop.sh

If you kill the parent.sh process the loop.sh process is taken care by the init process so it also execute again and again.

After parent.sh process is killed

   F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD

   1 S root     10005     2  0  80   0 -     0 worker 14:46 ?        00:00:00 [kwo rker/1:2]
   0 R 1047     10036     1 99  80   0 -  1290 -      14:46 ?        00:01:18 /bin/bash - ./loop.sh


You better need to kill both the process to kill whole process.
```